# Get value from database in autocomplete textview and show relative values in textviews

Tags: android

Suppose I have this database table:

```
Name: A,B,C,D

Id:   1,2,3,4

Phone no: 991,928,902,397
```

I am using an autocomplete textview for showing the names.the autocomplete code is here:

```
final ArrayList<String> s1 = new ArrayList<String>();


        for (StudentInfo cn : studentInfo) {
            s1.add(cn.getName());

        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,s1); 

        a1.setThreshold(1); 
        a1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here `a1 is the autocomplete textview`.Now If I select a name from autocomplete textview suppose B.Then the Id and Phone no of B is 2 and 902 which I want to show as 2 text view.Here actually I want to show the relative id and phone no of the name in two textview t1,t2.

```
a1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {


 }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Take a HashMap to map names with student details

```
HashMap<String, StudentInfo> studentdetails=new HashMap<String,StudentInfo>();
  for (StudentInfo cn : studentInfo) {
            s1.add(cn.getName());
            studentdetails.put(cn.getName(),cn);
        }
```

And it onItemClick get the values like this

```
a1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                    String studentname=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                   StudentInfo student=studentdetails.get(studentname);
                    // get values from studen record 

                 String id=student.getId();
                String phoneNumber=student.getPhone();

             }
        });
```

Comment: This works fine for names if I set like this t1.setText(studentname);.     studentdetails.put(cn.getName(),cn);StudentInfo student=studentdetails.get(studentname); these two lines is not necessary for showing the names.But how I get the Id or phone no relative to the name if I set it as text in two textview.